# Why is India branded as not a very liberal country?

Tags: india, liberalism

[image]

Despite being a democracy for 70 odd years, India scores low in many social rankings. Some examples:

- India is 87th of 144 in the [Global Gender Gap Report](http://reports.weforum.org/global-gender-gap-report-2016/rankings/), below average.
- India is 98th of 133 in the [Social Progress Index](http://www.socialprogressimperative.org/global-index/#data_table/countries/spi/dim1,dim2,dim3), well below average.
- India is 106th in Opportunity and Foundations of Well-Being.
- India is 141st of 180 in [Environmental Performance](http://epi.yale.edu/country-rankings).

In [this article](http://www.movehub.com/blog/the-most-liberal-countries-in-the-world), India is described as not a very liberal country. What are the reasons for the absence, or rather, slow growth of social equality in India?

Comment: What do you mean with "taking time"? You can't change the lifestyle and ethic values of over 1.3 billion people with diverse economical and sociocultural backgrounds over night.

Comment: Note that the definition used for "most liberal" is basically "factors such as gender equality, the rights of minorities, personal safety and environmental factors".

Comment: Also, I find it odd that there is no data for (South) Korea...

Comment: @sharur, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liberalism_in_South_Korea

Comment: @anonymous: I meant on the map, but thank you for your response and the link.

Comment: @sharur nor Taiwan

Answer (score 0):

According to your [link](http://www.movehub.com/blog/the-most-liberal-countries-in-the-world):

> Using data from the World Economic Forum’s Global Gender Gap Report 2016, the 2016 Social Progress Index report and Yale’s Environmental Performance Index 2016, MoveHub has created a completely unique list of the most liberal countries on the planet. To create the rankings MoveHub selected data from three reports that look at factors such as gender equality, the rights of minorities, personal safety and environmental factors such as soil, air and water quality.

So they seem to be using liberal in the United States sense (left wing), not in the European sense (center-right).  So being capitalist may not help them.

- India is 87th of 144 in the [Global Gender Gap Report](http://reports.weforum.org/global-gender-gap-report-2016/rankings/), below average.
- India is 98th of 133 in the [Social Progress Index](http://www.socialprogressimperative.org/global-index/#data_table/countries/spi/dim1,dim2,dim3), well below average.

  - India is 106th in Opportunity and Foundations of Well Being.
- India is 141st of 180 in [Environmental Performance](http://epi.yale.edu/country-rankings).

You may be able to find more detail in the PDF reports.

I find the following quote interesting:

> If you, like so many people in Trump’s America or post-Brexit Britain feel disconnected from your fellow countrymen and unsure about your future in your current country of residence and want to consider your options, do not worry, because MoveHub has compiled a list of the most liberal countries you could move to in 2017. Your liberal utopia is just a few clicks away...

Number ten on their most liberal list is the United Kingdom.  I'm not sure that they've thought through their propaganda if they recommend moving out of "Britain" and to the United Kingdom's "liberal utopia".  What's that mean?  Northern Ireland?

Comment: I'm sorry, but you don't seem to be answering the question. You are listing ratings various think tanks assigned to India in various criteria, but not what's the tendency and most importantly **why**. And the last half of your answer seem to have anything to do with India at all.

Comment: @Philipp  *Why* is that they picked three statistics to measure that don't correspond with those in the question.  The question talks about capitalism, secularism, and lack of corruption.  Those aren't the statistics being measured though.  The statistics are environment, gender gap, and social progress.  Secularism and corruption may impact Opportunity, but that is as subsubsubheadings of social progress.  The last two paragraphs suggest that this map isn't that serious an endeavor.  Someone seriously trying to measure "liberalness" would probably pick different measures.

Comment: This link shows the Netherlands as on par with Bulgaria and 2 shades less liberal than Belgium or Germany. It's gonna take some serious statistical gymnastics to come up with that result.